# Mysqli_query() error that doesn't make sense to me

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting the error:

```
Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /Users/phillipjordan/Desktop/Amatak/mule/settings/index.php on line 97
```

and I am not sure why because my code:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "_______";
$port = 8889;
$db = "****";
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("not working");
    die();
}
?>
*other code*
$settingsquery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE userid=".$_SESSION["id"]);
$setting = mysqli_fetch_assoc($settingsquery);
```

seems sound, could somebody help? It appears that the error comes from the mysqli_query() function specifically. I couldn't post more code because stackoverflow wouldn't let me.

Comment: you are mixing object-oriented approach to procedural approach.Don't do that. and please share your full code so that we can check.these two line of code leads every-one to guess only.

Comment: Probably your connection is not open.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AlivetoDie I know.

Comment: @Shadow What does that mean?

Comment: @AlivetoDie BTW, I switched from object-oriented to procedural and it still didn't work, it has something to do with the actual mysqli_query() itself.

Comment: @otherwall  as i said that you have to show your full code. We can't help with two line of code. We are not magicians.

Comment: Your connection to the MySQL database (represented by $conn) is probably not open, this is why you get the error message. The connection had probably been opened correctly, but was closed subsequently.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I made a stupid mistake where I put $conn->close(); before the functions, sorry to waste your time.